# Day's lemma and its proof in Robert E. Megginson's book

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

On the page 247 of the book *An introduction to Banach space theory* by Robert E. Megginson, there is a lemma to be used in the proof of the Eberlein-$\check{\text{S}}$mulian theorem:

> **2.8.5 Day's lemma** Let X be a normed space.
>
> (a) If A is a relatively weakly limit point compact subset of X and $x_0 \in \overline{A}^w$, then there is a sequence in A that converges weakly to $x_0$.
>
> (b) If $A_*$ is a relatively weakly limit point compact subset of $X^*$ and $x_0^* \in \overline{A_*}^{w^*}$, then there is a sequence in A that converges weakly to $x_0^*$.

Here are [pages](https://books.google.com/books?id=fD-GeCsqoqkC&pg=PA245&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false) from google books.

I have some questions concerning about the statement and some details in the proof.

> (1) I believe that part (b) should be
>
> **If $A_*$ is a relatively weakly-star limit point compact subset of $X^*$ and $x_0^* \in \overline{A_*}^{w^*}$, then there is a sequence in A that converges weakly-star to $x_0^*$** ,
>
> and correspondingly all of the "weak" convergences and "weak" closure in the proof should be replaced by "weak-star". Am I right?
>
> (2) In the second paragraph of the page 248, I don't understand why it follows easily from 
>   $$\|x^*\|\le 2~\text{sup}\{|x^*x|:x\in D\}, \forall x^* \in \langle \{x_n^*:n\in \mathbb{N} \} \rangle $$
>
> that
>
> $$\|x^*\|\le 2~\text{sup}\{|x^*x|:x\in D\}, \forall x^* \in [ \{x_n^*:n\in \mathbb{N} \} ] $$
>
> where $\langle S \rangle$ means the smallest subspace containing $S$ and $[ S ]$ means the smallest weakly-star closed subspace containing $S$.

For (2), is it legal to take a sequence in $\langle \{x_n^*:n\in \mathbb{N} \} \rangle$ weakly-star converging to $x^*$?(In general, we should take a net instead of a sequence.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement and proof in my book are correct as given. I have replied directly to the questioner with further information.

Comment: Concerning the question about legality of sequences: Certainly. Sequences are just special kinds of nets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply~~~however, if the statement and proof are correct, then there will be more questions coming up for both Day's lemma and Eberlein-$\check{\text{S}}$mulian theorem......